# PHP: How to download multiple files without using cURL and/or Zip?

Tags: php, curl, download, zip

I was wondering if I can download multiple files without using cURL and/or Zip. I want to create a file that if it's accessed, it will return 3 files simultaneously. Is it possible?

Comment: what would you expect from your browser when you click on a link to such a file?

Comment: No. You could trigger several popup's that would be used for downloading files.. but popup killers would block those.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for distributing multiple files is to base64 encode them and pass them back in a JSON array, this can be used to efficiently distribute the data, and then decide what to do with it once it arrives.

Of course if the client is strictly a web user, and not an API consumer, then this might not be ideal - as you'd have to still convert the base64 to a writeable file.  Nothing in Javascript for security reasons will be able to directly access filesystem.

Alternatively, you can make an ajax request to a URI that returns a given file with "Content-Disposition attachment", and then along with the users input (request next file), requests the next, etc. until all files are downloaded.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might just provide a list of links too!  Sometimes the easiest solution is the best.

Answer (score -1):

good old-fashioned (i.e. out-of-fashion) frames to the rescue!

```
<html>

  <frameset rows="33%,33%,33%">

    <frame src="file1.php" />
    <frame src="file2.php" />
    <frame src="file3.php" />

  </frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: this is generally insecure functionality - frames should almost never be used anymore.

Comment: frames are not limited to the origin/domain, i can use JS to write the src of any frame, and in this case, essentially causing the user to download malware if I want.  If you use ajax and no frames (or iframes) then content can only originate from the same domain.

Comment: I did indicate in my answer that frames are out of fashion. and the frames in my HTML reference content from the same site. there nothing insecure about that.